# Variables accessible across code files

Tags: c++, static, linker

Okay so I'm having a bit of an issue with creating variables that have the same value across all of my code files. Basically, I need to be able to create a variable, change it's value, and check it's new value inside of another code file. I'm almost positive the `static` keyword is what will fix this but I'd just like some confirmation before I test my code (my code isn't running on a machine I own, I'd have to contact someone to test the wares).

Comment: `static` keyword is quite the opposite then `extern`, since `static` variable can't been `extern`ed. if you use `static` you'll declare a different variable in each source file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use good old extern keyword.

e.g. file.cpp:

```
int myvar;
```

each file that want to use `myvar`:

```
extern int myvar;
```

Extern variable information can also be provided in a header file to avoid multiple variable definition.

Of course you can also create static field. somefile.h:

```
#ifndef _SOMEFILE_H
#define _SOMEFILE_H

class myclass{
public:
    static int mystaticfield;
};

#endif
```

somefile.cpp:

```
int myclass::mystaticfield;
```

each file that want to use `mystaticfield`:

```
#include "somefile.h"

// ...

myclass::mystaticfield = 9; //usage
```

Comment: instead of **another file** it more precise to write **each file** .

Comment: I saw something about that but it just confuses me a bit. What you're saying is that I would have to redeclare the variable in each source files?

Comment: No you just provide each file the information about an interface of the variable. To be more specific - what is the variable type as the address of variable will be provided at linking time.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly where the extern can be used.

Please find detailed information here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable